# Converting some rjs and prototype code to pure JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

So there's the following code from this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) for dynamically adding in a field for a nested model form:

This was in the application helper:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
  end
  link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')"))
end
```

And this was the javascript function:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Now I'm curious as to how you would change all of this code so that you could rely purely on JQuery and no prototype or rjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Prototype related thing here is `link_to_function` call. What it does is create `onclick` handler over your `name` text that calls your `add_fields` function.

So to be pure jquery you should use `$().click (function (){...})` method instead. However exact implementation will differ depending on whether you want to insert javascript in your html file or call it unobtrusively.